# How to use Parameters in the same page

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax

I am looking for way to use parameters in the same page by using input search. I don't want to the edit parameters for toolbar.

Please, I need a way for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the tool that you are using. Power BI doesn't support what you need.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov thank you :( I hope I can find a solution for that problem.